# C# How can i open page 2 with a button in page1?

Tags: c#

With button (page1) in mainwindow i can open page 1 and now i want to open page 2 with the button (page2) in page 1. For page 1 i used this code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            frame1.Content = new Page1();
        }
```

How can i open page 2 now?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating to a new page

```
Page1 p = new Page1();
frame1.Navigate(p);
```

**update**:

in mainWindow you add frame control (frame1), you set page1 in content property..

now, on click the button in Page1 add this code:

```
 Page2 p2 = new Page2();
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
```

Page2 button click:

```
Page1 p1 = new Page1();
this.NavigationService.Navigate(p1);
```

or use `this.NavigationService.GoBack();`

Comment: Doesn`t work. Error: The name `frame1` does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

//Inside your burton click event
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));

please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages